# Send prompt input to Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, input, process

I'm currently solving a problem of starting external tool from .net app.
I have this part of code:

```
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(_app, _args);
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

But, after starting application I get an error to StandartError output witn promt confirmation answer "enter y/n".
I've already tried to input "y" via standart input, right after starting process, but still get the same error.

```
 var standartInput = proc.StandardInput;
    standartInput.AutoFlush = true;
    standartInput.WriteLine("y");
    standartInput.Close();
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

PS: PuTTY Secure Copy client - is the external app I'm using from code. There is a confirmation promt, when running app for first time to save servers fingerprint in system registry.

Comment: You'd have to tell us about the external .net app and what is it expecting. It's really hard to tell here what the problem you're running into.

Comment: Thanks, Can you supply us some dummy args of what you are expecting to pass for PSCP ?

Comment: Can you run the app the first time manually to save the fingerprint, so you don't get the prompt on your subsequent automated runs? Or does it have a command line option to disable to prompting?

Comment: @ABKolan, -batch -i somekey someaddress/somefile somefile

Comment: @JasonWilliams, yes but that's not a solution for me, cuz I can't do it on all machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks OK to me. Maybe you need to sleep for a second or something before writing the "y". I would imagine that the program takes a little while to ask the user for input

Comment: Problem was in batch argument, pscp abandons connection automatically when batch attribute exists.